# Restrict some kibana users in a particular dashboard

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, authorization, logstash, kibana

I want to restrict some users in kibana, that users only able to access particular dashboards in Kibana.
I am using kibana version 6.0.0 . Currently I am using Searchguard for user authentication but can't able to restrict user on dashboard . Below is my current elasticsearch.yml file

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true

#action.auto_create_index: .security,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*



######## Start Search Guard Demo Configuration ########
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath: keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_filepath: keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- "CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test, C=de"
- "CN=node-0.example.com, OU=SSL, O=Test, L=Test, C=DE"
#searchguard.restapi.roles_enabled: ["sg_all_access"]


cluster.name: searchguard_demo
network.host: 0.0.0.0
######## End Search Guard Demo Configuration ########
```

Please do let me know if anyone having some idea.

Comment: Better to ask your question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/search-guard

Answer (score 0):

you can configure various users and their roles.
Step you can follow create custom role and configure kibana privilege

1. Go to Security -> Roles
2. Give Role a Name
3. Scroll at bottom you would see Kibana section there you can add various Kibana privileges for accessing Analytics, Observability, Security, Management.
4. Create your desired role and save it.
5. Then go to Security -> Users
6. select your user and assign the role which you just created

Answer (score -4):

You could install [**X-Pack**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/xpack-introduction.html) in your ELK Stack. Its an extension that bundles [**security**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/security-getting-started.html), **alerting, monitoring, reporting, and graph** capabilities into one easy-to-install package.

X-Pack supports features like:

- [Role-based Access Control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/authorization.html)
- [LDAP User Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/ldap-realm.html)
- [File-based User Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/file-realm.html)